# Can't unzip downloaded file with Python - Sentinel satellite data

Tags: python, zip, geospatial, unzip

I can't unzip a .zip file downloaded from Copernicus Open Access Hub. I retrieve the file and i try to unzip it using the following Python script:

```
from sentinelsat.sentinel import SentinelAPI
import zipfile

user = 's5pguest' 
password = 's5pguest' 

api = SentinelAPI(user, password, 'https://s5phub.copernicus.eu/dhus')

api.download("cb078cce-ed6e-46a7-a614-e13830b2a74a")

# The file is succesfully downloaded

zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("S5P_NRTI_L2__CO_____20191001T123303_20191001T123803_10188_01_010302_20191001T131513.zip", 'r')
zip_ref.extractall()
zip_ref.close()
```

The file is succesfully downloaded, but when it tries to unzip i get:

```
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-45c213a35459> in <module>
      9 api.download("cb078cce-ed6e-46a7-a614-e13830b2a74a")
     10 
---> 11 zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("S5P_NRTI_L2__CO_____20191001T123303_20191001T123803_10188_01_010302_20191001T131513.zip", 'r')
     12 zip_ref.extractall()
     13 zip_ref.close()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64)
   1129         try:
   1130             if mode == 'r':
-> 1131                 self._RealGetContents()
   1132             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1133                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1196             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1197         if not endrec:
-> 1198             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1199         if self.debug > 1:
   1200             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

If i try to unzip this file from the terminal with unzip i get:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of S5P_NRTI_L2__CO_____20191001T123303_20191001T123803_10188_01_010302_20191001T131513.zip or
        S5P_NRTI_L2__CO_____20191001T123303_20191001T123803_10188_01_010302_20191001T131513.zip.zip, and cannot find S5P_NRTI_L2__CO_____20191001T123303_20191001T123803_10188_01_010302_20191001T131513.zip.ZIP, period.
```

If i try with 7zip i get:

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=it_IT.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Processing archive: S5P_NRTI_L2__CO_____20191004T113803_20191004T114303_10230_01_010302_20191004T122457.zip

Error: Can not open file as archive
```

It seems like the file is corrupted, but if i try to download other files the error remains. 
I also tried to change the name in a simpler one like "doc.zip", without success.
I'm stucked, any ideas?

I'm following this tutorial https://github.com/acgeospatial/Satellite_Imagery_Python/blob/master/SentinelSat_Demo.ipynb

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct name of downloaded zip and and present in the same directory where your this python script running.

Comment: Have you tried opening it with a text editor?

Comment: The file is in the same script folder, however i also tried to open it using unzip on command line after cd in the correct folder.

Comment: Tried to open with gedit, but it's too big and the program crashes

Answer (score 0):

I think your file may not be a zip file probably.
Goto that files properties and check if its **.zip** format or not.

[image: Running proof]

And also i would like to mention that i wasn't able to open the repository you mentioned.

If you google the **7zip** error:
[image: Google error search]

Comment: Hi! The properties tab says it's a .zip file. If you take a look at the tutorial i linked the file is unzipped succesfully. I don't know why you can't use my script, did you install the sentinel module? I just run it again and it worked (only the download part)

Comment: Hello alcor, I tried opening the github repository it didn't workout for me

Comment: No, i dint download the sentinel module that's why i deleted those lines from my code. your download part is fine. there is something wrong with the file.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing. I'm going to send an email to the hub mantainers to ask for support.

Comment: It's not a hub maintainer thing. try using wpget from the command line and downloading the file manually maybe it'll work then

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug: https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat/issues/270
The file has an incorrect .zip extension. If i manually change the extension from .zip to .nc and try to open it with the viewer script, it works. I'm wondering how the tutorial i linked could work.